# How can I change ##-## space to ##-## tab?

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of entries that begin with 2 numbers, a dash, 2 numbers and a single space. For example (note the space after the numbers):

```
87-17
```

I need to change the above to `87-17<tab>` (where `<tab>` represent an actual tab character). I don't know how to write that out. I know it's simple but I'm not at all familiar with Linux, I'm just a lowly graphic designer...

Comment: I removed `grep` from your question since that is only a tool that searches through text files and not one that can change them easily.

Comment: Are there any lines in your input that don't look like that, which you would like to leave alone, or is just a case of substituting the last space on each line for a tab character? Some more input and corresponding output would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -ir 's/^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) /\1\t/' file
```

#### Explanation

`sed` is a "stream editor". Think of it as a simple programming language primarily designed to edit text. The `-i` option lets you edit the file in place. Run the command without the `-i` first to make sure it produces the desired result (the file will remain unchanged) and then run it with the `-i` to keep the changes. The `-r` enables extended regular extensions which, in this case, simplifies the format.

The `s/foo/bar/` is the "substitution operator". It will replace the first instance of `foo` on each line with `bar`. Here, we are feeding it a regular expression that means "match the beginning of the line (`^`), then two digits (`[0-9]{2}`), a minus `-`, another 2 digits and then a space. Because this pattern is inside parentheses, it is "captured" and made available as `\1`. Therefore, the command will replace it with itself followed by a tab (`\t`).

Or `perl`:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d{2}-\d{2}) /\1\t/' file
```

### Explanation

This is very similar to the `sed` above but using `perl`, another scripting language. The `-i` has the same function as it does for `sed`. The `-p` means "print every line after applying the script given to `-e` to it.

The substitution operator is again the same only that here we can use the `\d` shorthand for digits.

Comment: He, perl is my answer =)

Comment: It is great to see such well written answers. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

If you have just that space at the end you can use `tr`:

```
< file tr ' ' '\t' > file1
```

or `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/ /\t/' file
```

If there are other spaces which shouldn't be replaced:

```
sed -i 's/ $/\t/' file
```

Comment: `tr ' ' '\t' file > file1` gives `tr: extra operand ‘foo’`

Answer (score 1):

### Using `awk`

- If you really have only something like this `87-17<space>` in your file

  ```
  awk '/ $/ {printf "%s\t\n",$1}' foo > bar
  ```
- if not

  ```
  awk '/[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] $/ {printf "%s\t\n",$1}' foo > bar
  ```

---

### Using `gawk`

Maybe it's necessary to install `gawk` first

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

After that

```
gawk '{print gensub(/^([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})\s$/,"\\1\t","g")}' foo > bar
```

---

*Explanation*

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- 1st Capturing group `([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})`

  - `[0-9]{2}` match a single character present in the list below

    Quantifier: `{2}` Exactly 2 times

    `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - `\-` matches the character `-` literally
  - `[0-9]{2}` match a single character present in the list below

    Quantifier: `{2}` Exactly 2 times

    `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`
  - `$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: Much like @terdon 's answer, do you really need to match the whole pattern? Any reason I'm not seeing to do so?

Comment: @kos, not sure, but i believe, it's better to catch the whole string

Comment: Well I'll give you both that, maybe OP has a file slightly different from what he said, upvoted

Comment: @kos Same for you my friend =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tr** to convert characters. In the following example, I have converted spaces to tab.

```
echo '22-12 11-12' | tr ' ' '\t'
22-12   11-12
```